# dgrid - server side sorting

Tags: sorting, dojo, dgrid

I am trying to implement server side sorting with dojo dgrid control, and for that I was trying to hook up a handler on `dgrid-sort` event... but for some reason it is not invoked.

Any idea what I am missing in the following code. I can see the data in grid, also sorting (at client side) work as expected, but onSort event is not tiggered

My code:

```
var reportData = { .... .};
var columns = { /* { sortable : true } on each column */ };

require(["dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dojo/store/Memory"], function (Grid, Memory)
            {
                store = new Memory({ data: reportData });

                var grd = new Grid({
                    store: store,
                    columns: columns
                }, "grid");

                grd.on("dgrid-sort", onSort);

                function onSort(event)
                {
                    console.log("Sort invoked", event);

                    // Stop the normal sort event/bubbling
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();

                }

            });
```

Comment: Is there another part of your code that's listening to the "dgrid-sort" event? If not, is onSort defined somewhere else?

Comment: You are using a client side store. How do you expect to get a server side sort ? You should use dojo/store/JsonRest.

Comment: Solved. I was using an older version of dgrid and dgrid-sort event implementation was missing..! @Philippe - I just wanted to hook an eventHandler on grid sort event, so I can disable the client side sorting, and invoke server side sort api. Thanks

Comment: Having some similar issues myself. Can you provide any more detail on your dgrid versoin? Is "grid" where you're placing it a dom object / id ?